How to restore /etc/X11 folder
I use Arch, btw.
Accidentally, I removed the entire X11 folder while setting up my Wayland configuration, which is why Sway won't start.
How can I restore the folder?
P.S.: pacman -R xorg && pacman -Sy xorg doesn't work

try to reinstall the xorg packages

Restore from your most recent backup?

I want the solution without backups

When you remove directories, particularly ones that are customized to your environment and are protected by root permissions, backups are necessary.

As i wrote in the comments, try to reinstall xorg-xinit.
Try:
sudo pacman -S --needed --overwrite="*" xorg-server xorg-xinit

or
xorg and other related xorg packages.
sudo pacman -S xorg-xinit xorg-server xorg-xrdb xorg-xrandr xorg-xauth xorg-xsetroot

Check this:
how to re-install X from terminal
What @Ljm Dullaart wrote in the answer:
If reinstall not work try to copy with rsync or cp all files and folders from a new installation.
pacman
Xorg Arch Wiki

Without backup there is no restore. Sorry.
The best you can do is to try to copy the files from a fresh install (install the same distribution on a USB stick and copy from that USB stick) or try to re-install the X11 packages.
